# Google Analytics API iOS v3 keeps showing users as active after app quits

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics

I was using Google Analytics API v2 and it was working great. When a user open my app, it will show up on the real time analysis and if the user quits the app, that user was not showing up anymore on that report. That took it around 20 or 30 seconds.

But using the new session management suggested by Google on the Analytics API v3, it took almost 3 minutes for a user to disappear from the real time report after quitting my app.

This is the code that I'm using when launching my app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
....
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = NO;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Initialize tracker.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"XX-YYYYYYYY-Z"];

[tracker set:kGAISessionControl value:@"start"];
}
```

And this is the code to end analytics session:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"XX-YYYYYYYY-Z"];

[tracker set:kGAISessionControl value:@"end"];
}
```

Is this code correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Of course google analytics got a litle delay, but it's not annoying I think. Your code is right, and as I read it works right. So don't worry. Sometimes it s really on time, sometimes got a little delay.

and I recomend to set `[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;` this will reduce your delay.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two things:

1) You need to **generate one "hit" after each session control call** (they don't result in analytics update in of themselves -- "The next hit from this tracker will be the first in a new session." -- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions).

2) You need to **reset the session control value back to nil** after issuing the first event. ("Setting session control directly on the tracker persists the value across all subsequent hits, until it is manually set to null." -- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration)

**Note:** Although https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#session states "A value of 'start' forces a new session to start with this hit and 'end' forces the current session to end with this hit. All other values are ignored.", with the iOS SDK, this does not appear to be the case: **Using a value of "" to clear the session control value seems to disrupt session timing** (i.e., yields correct session counts, but session times of 0:00).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still don't understand. On the second note, don't you want your tracker keeps the same session for upcoming hits? If you can add some examples, it would be great